# What is the derivative of $y = x^{x+1}$

Tags: calculus

Can someone walk me through how to solve this derivative? We went over it as such:

$y = x^{x+1}$

Then take the natural log (ln) of both sides

$\ln(y) = (x+1)\ln(x)$

I get lost as to why that equality exists

$y' = \left(\ln x + \dfrac{x+1}{x}\right)\cdot y$

$y' = \left(\ln x + \dfrac{x+1}{x}\right) x^{x+1}$

I am just unsure as to how/why you take the natural log of both sides.

Comment: In questions where we need to calculate derivatives of $g(x)^{f(x)}$ we usually follow this approach. I don't have an explanation though

Answer (score 2):

This process is called *logarithmic derivative*. Nothing really special, it's just the chain rule: the derivative of $\log f(x)$ is
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
because the derivative of $\log x$ is $1/x$.

Since you have $f(x)=x^{x+1}$, you also have
$$
\log f(x)=(x+1)\log x
$$
so, differentiating both sides,
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\log x+(x+1)\frac{1}{x}
$$
and you're done.

Comment: So, just for clarification, is your final answer the same as mine? They look completely different to me, I like your answer much better.

Comment: @user216150 The answers are the same: $f'(x)=(\log x+(x+1)/x)x^{x+1}$

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to log both sides if you really don't want to:

$y=x^{x}=e^{x \ln x}$, which you can easily differentiate with the chain rule.

To answer your question, logging both sides just gives us a simpler equation to differentiate.

Comment: Well, by rewriting it as an exponential, you're basically taking the log of both sides anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's just to bring the expression down from the exponent as a multiplier, thanks to the properties of the logarithm (taking advantage of the fact that $\log a^b = b\log a$). The price of this is that you have introduced a logarithm into the expression, but that's easy to handle for differentiation.